# How to run a Python code inside a custom package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Suppose my folder looks like:

```
├── main.py
└── package
    ├──__init__.py
    ├──utils.py
    └──method.py
```

In my `method.py`, I import the `utils.py`, which is in the same directory, so I put the dot before the name:

```py
from .utils import *
```

then I can run the script in `main.py` like:

```py
from package import method
```

This will work. But the question is, how I can run the script in `method.py` at its directory instead of importing it in `main.py`? If I run the script `method.py` directly, an error will occur:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.modules'; '__main__' is not a package
```

What can I do to run the script in `method.py` without removing the dot as `from utils import *`?

Comment: Did you try running `python -m package.method` ?

Comment: Can you add code for `method.py`? I think, somewhere you're trying to do `from __main__ import something`

Answer (score 2):

To make your code work, change the `import` statement in `method.py` from

```
from .utils import *
```

to

```
import __main__, os

if os.path.dirname(__main__.__file__) == os.path.dirname(__file__):
    # executed script in this folder
    from utils import *
else:
    # executed script from elsewhere
    from .utils import *
```

When `method.py` runs, it checks the folder that the executed python script is in, and if it's the same folder as itself, it will import `utils`, rather than `.utils`.

You can achieve a similar thing using

```
if __name__=='__main__':
```

as your check. However, if `method.py` is imported by anther file inside the `package` folder, then `method.py` will try to import `.utils`, and won't be able to find it.